# Why do we inject database context in repositories instead of creating database context inside repository class itself?

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

One of the objectives of Repository pattern is supposed to decouple business logic with data access. Then why is it that database context is not created in repository class itself instead of being provided to it by service layer or controller?

Comment: It *shouldn't* be provided by the service layer or controller. These should have a dependency on the repository only. Whoever creates that repository should inject the context. The controller/service layer shouldn't even know there's a context involved.

Comment: In unit tests, the repository is constructed by the unit test code. In the application, it's typically created by the DI container. The repository itself should provide significant functionality on top of the ORM, not just a GetAll, Insert, Update.

Comment: Yeah but what is the need to inject database context at all? Why not let the repository handle the job of creating the database context to whichever database it needs to access?

Comment: I inject a ContextFactory into my repositories so it can wrap all the calls in a using statement and close it as soon as it is finished instead of letting the DI deal with it.  However, if you want to utilize the tracking changes, the context has to exist before mapping the changes to the entity, which tends to happen outside of the repository... Unless you move the mapping to the repository in some way - maybe just inject the mapper and call it inside the using statement, but then the repository has to know about Dtos or business objects from above.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the context in because you may have a transaction that spans repositories.  The context is the unit of work for the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Database Context represents your Unit Of Work in most cases. With this in mind, there are at least two reasons to inject it in repositories instead of creating it in repositories.

1. Using same Context across multiple repositories
   Many articles say Transaction is responsibility of Repository. But, in practical world, this may not be the case every time. One may need to span the transaction across multiple repositories. To achieve this, there is no better way than to inject it.
2. Manage Context at some higher level (Context per Request in Web may be) which is not accessible to Repository
   This is not much different than above. Many implementations manage Context at higher level which is not accessible to Repositories. Context per Request is popular example. In this case, Context must be separated somehow from Repositories and handled differently. But, repositories does need the Context; so just inject it.

Contexts exposed by full ORMs implement change tracking at good scale. To take better advantage of this feature, it is better if Context is separated from Repositories.

Imagine the case where your repository call is successful but you do not want to flush because your other file action failed.

By separating Context from Repository, you better implement SRP. Context handles responsibility of Change Tracking and Flushing. Repository hold in-memory representation of data with changes if any and allows to read/write this in-memory data.